# REGEX match for portions of a document between two headers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, multiline

I'm trying and failing to write a python compliant REGEX that captures multiple parts of a document. My code will actually be in Python, but right now i've only tried on regex101.com to get the expression right. (unsuccessfully obviously :) )

My text that is file-based, looks something like this:

<#
.SYNOPSIS
This is the synopsis text, that is a multiline
synopsis - I want to match all of this text
as a capture group.
.PARAMETER
This a another block of
multiline text that I want to capture
.SOMEOTHER HEADER
And some other multiline text
#

I'd like to capture 2 groups (the header and the body text), globally. (i.e for each section).

My ultimate aim is a python array of dictionaries like;

[
{'header':'SYNOPSIS', 'text': }
{'header':'PARAMETER', 'text': }
]

The header section is always anchored to the beginning the line, with '.' and followed by uppercase TEXT. The body of the section includes any words and non-word characters including CR/LF (windows based).

The Header names are not guaranteed to be fixed literals, or in a specific order. Nor do I know how many headers might exist.

Right now it looks like this
`(^\.[A-Z]+)([\n\W\w]+)`

Right now I can match the header followed by a body, but I'm having a hard time telling REGEX to essentially 'stop looking when you hit the next .HEADERTEXT'.

I've created a Regex101 https://regex101.com/r/YqibeH/4 if its of use (not sure how this might work out). . .

My psuedo code says something like,

Find all lines beginning with ^.[A-Z] as a capture group, then continue to match all text (multiline) after the header as a second capture group. Stop capturing just before the next header that begins ^.[A-Z]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will `.SOMEOTHER HEADER` always be named `.SOMEOTHER HEADER`?

Comment: No - Could be anything. The last part of the document to stop any match is the #>.

Comment: You could use positive lookaheads like so. `(^\.SYNOPSIS[\n\W\w]+)(?=\.NOTES)([\n\W\w]+)(?=#>)`. https://regex101.com/r/YqibeH/6

Comment: OK - My bad - Should have said, the Header names are not guaranteed to be fixed literals, or in a specific order

Nor do I know how many headers might exist

Comment: Oh Ok. that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is look aheads. Additionally the search you were doing is greedy and should be changed out for a lazy quantifier. That being said. This should work.

`^\.\w+[\n\W\w]+?(?=^\.\w+|^#>)`
https://regex101.com/r/YqibeH/7

`^\.\w+` Greedily captures your header text.

`[\n\W\w]+?` Lazily searches for your body text.

`(?=^\.\w+|^#>)` until it looks ahead and finds either a line beginning with another header text or a line beginning with a header closing tag.

Note that if the greedy quantifier `+` would be used rather than `+?` it would continue matching until the last possible instance it could match.

Comment: You've nailed - thanks @axe319. Your'e right the greedy quantifiers have been hurting me more than I realised. 

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '<#\n.SYNOPSIS\nThis is the block of code that I would like to have matched along with the .SYNOPSIS header, ' \
       'as this block belongs to SYNOPSIS\n .NOTES\n This block needs to belong with\nNOTES ' \
       'header\n.SOMEOTHERHEADER\nAnd resulting text\n\n#> '
pattern = "(\.[A-Z]+\n)+"
import re

print(re.split(pattern, text))
```

If I got your problem right, I solved it in the following way. This way you have a list with all the elements that you need to be appendend to your dictionary by cleaning the string, of course.

Comment: Thanks for this - I implemented a combination of @Axe319 with a little tweak for capture groups to get into the format I wanted.